# How to source images in HTML that are encrypted

Tags: html, image, security, encryption, asp-classic

I am trying to keep my images safe by having an encryption on them.  I've used an encryption program called "AxCrypt" to encrypt my images, but it changes the image file extension.  For example, image.jpg becomes image-jpg.axx.  Whenever the image wants to be opened, it would ask for a password, which is great!  However, now I want to be able to source the image from within my code.  I am using HTML and Classic ASP to code the page, when I see it in a browser, the image comes out blank.

My reasoning for this is because I need to put the images on a server, but need the images to remain secure and inaccessible by other users, but would still need to show the images on my web page.  Is there any way to keep my image files secure but still source and use them on my web page?

Thanks in advance!
Jason

Comment: Can't you use Windows permissions to secure the files? e.g. turn off read permissions except for your own user and the anonymous IIS user.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop other people from downloading your images that are on the server.
The simplest way for somebody who doesn't know programing is doing a simple print screen.

There are options to keep your images safe, but you need to use Flash movie.

You can make copyright ownership of the images and i thing is going to be fine.

Comment: What specific options would I have if I used Flash movie?  Thanks.

Comment: I am not referring to the front end where users can see the images on the webpage, I am referring to the back end on the server side.  I work in the IT Department in a school, and there are multiple users that can gain access to our school's servers.  Therefore, I need a secure mechanism back end for the images but still be able to source them to a webpage.  If there are any other solutions, that would be great.  Thanks.